# Deploy app only using shell

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, putty, node-oracledb

I need to deploy a node app in the client machine. I'm accessing the client environment through putty, an SSH client and I already have Nodejs and NPM installed and also the project in the client machine. When I try to run I get the following error:

[image: Error Log]

Looking to the error I need to install Oracle DB Client. My question is: How can I do this in the putty shell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s seems that you don’t have installed the oracledb as it says “if you don’t have il oracledb installed on this machine[...]”

Comment: Yes, but how can I install it with putty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for that error in the [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20njs-045), you'll find lots of explanations. It's likely that you haven't installed the client libraries that the module depends on. You'll need to download and install those. See the [installation instructions](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html) for details. If you need to use the command line, look into using SCP to upload the libraries, then you can install them with Putty.